# How to access Device Crash Logs on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: video, windows-phone-8.1, crash-reports, crash-dumps, lumia

We are developing a video rendering app for windows phone 8.1 and are hitting a roadblock.  The phone restarts when we call VideoComposition.RenderToFileAsync to combine multiple video clips. It only happens on one of our two devices... The Lumia 535.

We've tried to access the Debug Folder in Documents on the phone but there is no dmp for the crash from our app.  The fact that the phone is restarting may have something to do with that.

We've tried to use Field Medic which does record 'OS Crash 0000014B' under the 'Uploads' tab.  But we are not able to view the contents of this crash.  I'm curious where this log is uploaded and if I have access to it either locally or wherever it was uploaded to.

Or perhaps there is another way to approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: Since this is a Lumia 535, the field medic log have most likely being uploaded to the SD Card. You would need to open a support ticket with Microsoft in order to analyze the field medic logs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I went to make a support ticket and it appears as though it would cost me $499.00. Is that correct?

Comment: 0000014B = SOC_SUBSYSTEM_FAILURE Do you use the Denim update on Phone 8.1?

Comment: Thanks! The phone that is crashing is on Denim.  The phone that works is on Cyan.   I didn't realize they were different, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.     Any insights on what I need to do?  Are there known issues with Denim?

Comment: I'm not a windows phone expert, so I can't really answer if there are any known issues. Some users get the  Phone 8.1 GDR2 via the Insider App which is used to receive the Win10 TP. Maybe the GDR2 fixes the issue

Comment: We've confirmed with Microsoft that this crash is an issue with the OS on this device.  Though that doesn't answer the larger question of how to retrieve crash logs from the device when the phone reboots.